# Django migrations detect the same change many times

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a model like this:

```
MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        editable=True
    )

    date_end = models.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=3)
    )

...
```

I modified the `date_end` field before, and I did the migrations, it is working properly, but now it is still detecting that change as a new migration. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are *calling* `datetime.now()` in the default parameter of the definition. That means that the default changes each time you start Django, so the system thinks you need a new migration.

You should wrap that calculation into a lambda function, which will be called as necessary:

```
date_end = models.DateTimeField(
    default=lambda: datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=3)
)
```

**Edit**

If the lambda causes problems, you can move the code into a separate function and pass that as the default instead:

```
def default_end():
    return datetime.now() + relativedelta(months=3)

...

date_end = models.DateTimeField(
        default=default_end
)
```

Note here we're passing the function object, not the result, as the default param.

Comment: That was the problem, but is there other way to define it? I used lambda but I got `ValueError: Cannot serialize function: lambda`

Comment: Sorry for asking again.. but I have defined `default_end` inside and outside `MyModel` class but I got error when I run `makemigrations`